# Citrix on Windows 10 with display scaling

Tags: windows-10, scaling, citrix-receiver

I'm using Citrix Receiver for Windows 4.10.1.22 on Surface Pro 4
Virtual Desktop runs fine all the time, but when I'm trying  to run any other citrix app if external display with different scaling is connected -- it doesn't work -- the mouse pointer jumps around and I can't click on anything.

I thought It's Citrix Receiver issue, but I have it installed on another HP notebook that also has external display connected with different scaling (150% on main display, 100% on external display) -- it works just fine.
Moreover, I connected same Surface to another display with same scaling -- and citrix apps worked fine.

Should I reinstall something, and how? To get Citrix app working if different scaling display is connected. The display it's not working is Samsung SyncMaster 2333.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue about Citrix Receiver for Windows 4.10

In a multi-monitor setup with each monitor set to different DPI, when you enable the relative mouse in a session, the mouse movement is not steady. As a workaround, set the DPI scaling only to 100% on both the monitors when using the relative mouse functionality.

Also check:

Display DPI scaling configuration with Receiver for Windows

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX230017

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. Autoscale must be disabled in citrix settings. I recorded a video, look https://youtu.be/JpTJE_z6r7Q